# Weak second order Logic

Tags: logic, higher-order-logic, second-order-logic

I was [reading](https://web.archive.org/web/20160910094248/http://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/file/10994/tata.pdf) the other day (Chapter 3 Introduction), that

> sequential calculus is also called weak second order monadic logic with one successor or WS1S.

I understand the difference between first-order and second-order logic and also the one successor parts. What is a "weak" MSO? SO, what is it weaker than?

Comment: Keep reading. It covers SkS later.

Comment: could you leave the full citation of the text, the link is broken

Comment: I've changed the link to an Archive.org page since the original was broken.

Comment: For future reference, the text is: Comon, Hubert. “Tree automata techniques and applications.” (1997).

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody stumbles upon this question, it would be a crime to leave it unanswered. In the Semantics of WSkS (Section 3.3.2 Semantics of the book) it says

> the logic SkS is defined ... except that set variables may be interpreted as infinite sets.

By contrast, in case of WSkS, they are finite sets.